# python function for searching videos in Vimeo

Tags: python, search, video

https://github.com/floris-vos/vimeo_search_python

I made a small function that takes search terms as arguments and returns a dictionary with items, each holding an URL, title, duration, channel, and date published for a search result (the title is the key; a format that I have found extremely useful).
The function uses the Requests module, so bypasses the need for API.
It's kind of inspired by: https://pypi.org/project/youtube-search/

Just on a side note: I'm working on similar code for Dailymotion, and probably might in the end just make a tool that can search all big streaming websites. Still figuring out how to put it in PIP.

It works just fine, but any improvements would of course be interesting:

```
from requests import get as request
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
from json import loads

class vimeo_search:

    def search_vimeo(self, search_terms):
        encoded_search = quote_plus(search_terms)
        item = {}
        url = f"https://vimeo.com/search?q={encoded_search}"
        try:
            headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36'}
            response = request(url, timeout=10, headers=headers).text
        except: 
            return
        index1 = response.index("vimeo.config = ")
        index1 = response.index("[", index1)
        index2 = response.index("}}}]", index1) + 4
        text = response[index1:index2]
        dicti = loads(text)
        results = dict()
        for song in dicti:
            url = song["clip"]["link"]
            title = song["clip"]["name"]
            play_time = song["clip"]["duration"]
            date = song["clip"]["created_time"]
            channel = song["clip"]["user"]["name"]
            results[title] = {
                "url": url,
                "play_time":play_time,
                "date":date[:9],
                "channel":channel,
                "title":title
            }
        return results
```

:::::::::EXAMPLE:::::

To search for Johnny Cash videos:

```
vimeo = vimeo_search()

print(vimeo.search_vimeo("johnny cash"))
```

Returns:

```
{'The Johnny Cash Project': {'url': 'https://vimeo.com/15416762', 'play_time': 347, 'date': '2010-09-3', 'channel': 'Chris Milk', 'title': 'The Johnny Cash Project'}, 'YELAWOLF "Johnny Cash"': {'url': 'https://vimeo.com/130398770', 'play_time': 266, 'date': '2015-06-1', 'channel': 'Martin Linss', 'title': 'YELAWOLF "Johnny Cash"'}, 'Johnny Cash - Hurt': {'url': 'https://vimeo.com/213515290', 'play_time': 237, 'date': '2017-04-1', 'channel': 'Racerboy Roy', 'title': 'Johnny Cash - Hurt'}, 'Johnny Cash - Solitary Man': {'url': 'https://vimeo.com/46188490', 'play_time': 147, 'date': '2012-07-2', 'channel': 'MetalMicha', 'title': 'Johnny Cash - Solitary Man'}, 'Johnny Cash': {'url': 'https://vimeo.com/38894934', 'play_time': 175, 'date': '2012-03-2', 'channel': 'Dan Cohoes', 'title': 'Johnny Cash'}, 'The Wanderer by Johnny Cash': {'url': 'https://vimeo.com/40623057', 'play_time': 284, 'date': '2012-04-1', 'channel': 'Matt Devir', 'title': 'The Wanderer by Johnny Cash'}, 'Johnny Cash - Folsom Prison Blues (Pete Rock Remix)': {'url': 'https://vimeo.com/2925003', 'play_time': 181, 'date': '2009-01-2', 'channel': 'John West', 'title': 'Johnny Cash - Folsom Prison Blues (Pete Rock Remix)'}, 'Johnny Cash - Hurt (Legendado)': {'url': 'https://vimeo.com/16554146', 'play_time': 232, 'date': '2010-11-0', 'channel': 'Rafael', 'title': 'Johnny Cash - Hurt (Legendado)'}, '"One", Johnny Cash': {'url': 'https://vimeo.com/145911240', 'play_time': 233, 'date': '2015-11-1', 'channel': 'Shangrila Club', 'title': '"One", Johnny Cash'}, 'Johnny Cash - Heart of gold': {'url': 'https://vimeo.com/49962875', 'play_time': 182, 'date': '2012-09-2', 'channel': 'Nelsony23', 'title': 'Johnny Cash - Heart of gold'}, 'Still Hurtin - Johnny Cash (RetroSpector Mix)': {'url': 'https://vimeo.com/4230107', 'play_time': 437, 'date': '2009-04-1', 'channel': 'Phil RetroSpector', 'title': 'Still Hurtin - Johnny Cash (RetroSpector Mix)'}, 'Johnny Cash "Farther Along" | Official Music Video': {'url': 'https://vimeo.com/gabrieltick/johnnycash-fartheralong', 'play_time': 236, 'date': '2021-01-0', 'channel': 'gabriel tick', 'title': 'Johnny Cash "Farther Along" | Official Music Video'}, 'The Johnny Cash Project Documentary by Radical Media': {'url': 'https://vimeo.com/18157343', 'play_time': 344, 'date': '2010-12-2', 'channel': 'Livio Rajh', 'title': 'The Johnny Cash Project Documentary by Radical Media'}, 'Johnny Cash - Wayfaring Stranger': {'url': 'https://vimeo.com/62079563', 'play_time': 200, 'date': '2013-03-1', 'channel': 'Peter', 'title': 'Johnny Cash - Wayfaring Stranger'}, 'Johnny Cash at Folsom Prison - Trailer': {'url': 'https://vimeo.com/12030988', 'play_time': 134, 'date': '2010-05-2', 'channel': 'Northern Light Productions', 'title': 'Johnny Cash at Folsom Prison - Trailer'}, 'Johnny Cash - Spiritual': {'url': 'https://vimeo.com/31212811', 'play_time': 308, 'date': '2011-10-2', 'channel': 'westend_zoo', 'title': 'Johnny Cash - Spiritual'}, 'Johnny Cash - Personal Jesus': {'url': 'https://vimeo.com/94636060', 'play_time': 200, 'date': '2014-05-0', 'channel': 'WidziszTo.com', 'title': 'Johnny Cash - Personal Jesus'}}
```

EDIT:
Just in case the above is of use to anybody, here is a link to similar code for Dailymotion. Others to come.
https://github.com/floris-vos/daily-motion-search-python/tree/main

Answer (score 2):

I would change results to be a list, because `title` is not unique. Using a non-unique string as a key could mean `result` returns with fewer results then are on the page. Also you define variables `url`, `title`, etc but you don't manipulate them, so just setting the object with the value directly might be cleaner

```
results = []
for song in dicti:
    results.append({
        "url": song["clip"]["link"],
        ...
    })
```

This would mean results has a different format but the title is a key/value inside results object items still.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!
As to your first tip, I think that I will rather enumerate them (append (1), (2), etc to duplicates), because I found that making a dictionary is kind of handy because putting them in a list only requires list(results.keys()).  But good tip anyways, they are indeed not unique!

Also, yes, I can leave out those non-manipulated variables! Will change as suggested (and imply it in the Dailymotion searcher and other future searchers)